# Using the Android phone VPN on my PC

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, http-proxy

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. I want to connect to a VPN service on my Android phone. Then, I want to be able to use that VPN service on my PC. I have tried using the Hotspot tethering option on Android phone and while that allowed me to use the connection on my phone, it bypassed the VPN service. I have tried using a proxy app that allows me to turn the phone into a proxy server in which I can use my PC to connect to by setting proxy on my PC, that worked but only if the VPN service is disconnected. If I connect to the VPN service prior to or after attempting to connect to the proxy, my PC would not be able to connect to the proxy. Note that my phone is connected to the internet by wifi (not data) and that both my phone and PC are on the same local network. Also, note that the phone is not rooted.

Comment: What VPN and VPN type? With OpenVPN, there should be an option within the OpenVPN client to route all traffic through the VPN _(the official OpenVPN app leaves a lot to be desired and has really poor functionality, instead use [OpenVPN for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn))_

Comment: @JW0914 Not OpenVPN app sadly. It is a propriety app called Transocks. I want to use its service on my PC. The PC version of it is paid. Though the Android version runs for free with ads.